# My jekyll blog keeps trying to use the old jekyll, and I can't figure out why

Tags: ruby, jekyll, macos-catalina

I periodically update my blog using Jekyll. Today I tried to do that and I had to update Ruby (perhaps because I upgraded to Catalina, not sure), which lead to a TON of ruby deprecation warnings. So I figured I’d update Jekyll.

For the life of me I can't get `bundle exec jekyll build` to use the new Jekyll. I thought perhaps it was because I was relying on jekyll-assets, which depends on jekyll < 4.0. So I removed that dependency from my gemfile, and finally got `gem update` to install Jekyll 4.0. But `bundle exec jekyll build` still tries to run Jekyll 3.8.6.

Googling, all I can find are people who want to run older versions, not people stuck running older versions.

Grepping through my jekyll source, I can't find anything that references 3.8.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Does your `Gemfile.lock` have the correct version? Does `bundle show` list the correct version? If you really don't want the older version, nuke it with `gem remove jekyll`.

Comment: Ah, I had deleted it, but I guess it got regenerated, and shows the wrong jekyll. Deleting it again and running `bundle exec jekyll build`, it’s now using the right jekyll. Alas, I still get the deprecation warning `jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:41: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated`

Comment: If you're using Ruby 2.7 you get all the good new stuff, but you also get a whole heap of warmings about subtle changes in Ruby syntax that are forthcoming. These may have already been reported upstream, but it's worth checking the Jekyll issues if you think you can resolve that.

Comment: If you want to ignore deprecation warnings, among other things, `export RUBYOPT=-W0` turns them off in your shell. These are good to have for your code, but just plain annoying for dependencies. Ruby doesn't distinguish.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @tadman, I deleted the `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle exec jekyll build`, and now it’s using the right jekyll. Sadly, this doesn't fix the deprecation warning, but that’s for another question.